# Python script won't print when called from another python script

Tags: python

I have two scripts. The first script outputs to a file a list of folders and files, then it calls a second python script to read that file and print it to screen. The second script is called but nothing ever prints to the screen and I'm not sure why. No error message is thrown.

First Script:

```
#!/bin/python

from subprocess import call
import os.path
import os

def main():
    userRequest=raw_input("""Type the path and folder name that you'd like to list all files for.
The format should begin with a slash '/' and not have an ending slash '/'
Example (/var/log) *Remember capital vs. lower case does matter* :""")
    userInputCheck(userRequest)

def userInputCheck(userRequest):
    lastCharacter=userRequest[-1:]
    if lastCharacter=="/":
        userRequest=userRequest[:-1]
    folderCheck=os.path.isdir(userRequest)
    if folderCheck != True:
        print("\nSorry, '"+userRequest+"' does not exist, please try again.\n")
        requestUserInput()
    else:
        extractFileList(userRequest)

def extractFileList(userRequest):
    fileList=open('/tmp/fileList.txt', 'a')
    for folderName, subFolderName, listFiles in os.walk(userRequest):
        fileList.write(folderName+":\n")
        for fileName in listFiles:
            fileList.write(fileName+"\n")
        fileList.write("\n")   
    fileList.close
    os.system("readFile.py /tmp/fileList.txt")

if os.path.isfile("/tmp/fileList.txt"):
    os.remove("/tmp/fileList.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Second Script:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys

userFile=sys.argv[1]

f = open(userFile, 'r')
fileInfo=f.read()
sys.stdout.write(fileInfo)
sys.stdout.flush()
f.close
```

Comment: `f.close` != `f.close()`

Comment: Are you _sure_ `readFile.py` is executed? How do you know? Anyway you'd be safer executing it with `python readFile.py /tmp/fileList.txt`. Add some diagnostic messages so you can see what happens. Also, why not just print with `print()`? And yes, you must write `fileList.close()`-- did you view `/tmp/fileList.txt` to confirm that it is not empty?

Comment: @RonNorris, that's not how it works. This should not be a problem.

Comment: The comment by juanpa.arrivillaga is the right answer - @RyanL without the parentheses `close` isn't being called so the content hasn't necessarily been flushed to the file when the second script executes.

Comment: Yep, adding the parentheses fixed it. Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga I appreciate the help. I completely missed that.